# convert Column values into Row values

Tags: sql, database

i have a table like below

```
   structure_no  |   element_name
        1        |      BASIC
        1        |      HRA
        2        |      BASIC
        2        |      HRA
```

I would like to get the values

```
   structure_no    |  element1   | element2
        1          |  BASIC      |   HRA 
        2          |  BASIC      |   HRA
```

Kindly help me in forming SQL Query

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you need assistance writing a query, you need to first attempt something yourself. Please update your question with the attempt you've made and where you're struggling.

Comment: @Krishnamoorthy - before posting a question on Stack Overflow, please try Googling the name of your question and seeing what comes up.  "SQL convert columns to rows" (or "SQL convert rows to columns", which is actually what you're trying to do) will return hundreds of results, all of which use the PIVOT operator.

Comment: Instead of returning from sql you would be better off if you do it in the front end. What technology do you use? if you happen to use C# then may be using LINQ groupby to get what you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **SOLUTION APPROACH 1**

Using Oracle 11G's pivot option, you can do as below:

```
SELECT *
   FROM   MY_DATA_TABLE
  PIVOT (MIN(ELEMENT_NAME)
   FOR    ELEMENT_NAME  IN ('BASIC' AS ELEMENT1,'HRA' AS ELEMENT2) );
```

Refer Fiddle Here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7f4cd/2

- **SOLUTION APPROACH 2:**

You can also use decode and aggregate function with group by as below:

```
SELECT STRUCTURE_NO,
MAX(DECODE (ELEMENT_NAME,'BASIC',ELEMENT_NAME)) ELEMENT1,
MAX(DECODE (ELEMENT_NAME,'HRA',ELEMENT_NAME)) ELEMENT2
FROM SAMPLE_TABLE
GROUP BY STRUCTURE_NO;
```

Refer Fiddle Here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7f4cd/4

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done. There is no way to have a set number of fields. You can get a count of all records with that `structure_no` and you can select all records with that `structure_no` but I do not believe what you are trying to do can be done with a query.

Perhaps reconsider your table structure and the use of relationships.